# Message screenshots to text transcription (OCR or OCR replacement)

Tags: ocr

Would anyone recommend the easiest and (hopefully) cheapest method to achieve this scenario in an app.

1. The user screenshots (or exports) a text message
2. The user goes into the app to upload (or import) this screenshot to text message
3. The app is able to recreate the conversation
4. The users can then continue the conversion in the app (because it's also a messaging app) - This is just for context.

Considering using OCR but most seem very expensive. Any other AI alternatives would be great, if there are any recommendations.

Thank you!